# gulp quitting after dependent task

Tags: node.js, gulp

What am I missing?  Gulp is quitting **without error** after my dependent task.  `styles` does not continue after `styles-clean`:

```
var args = require('yargs').argv;
var config = require('./gulp.config')();
var del = require('del');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({lazy: true});

gulp.task('styles', ['clean-styles'], function() {
  log('Compiling less...');
  return gulp
      .src(config.less)
      .pipe($.less())
      .on('error', errorLogger)
      .pipe($.autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 version', '> 5%']}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(config.temp));
});

gulp.task('clean-styles', function(done){
  var files = config.temp + '**/*.css';
  clean(files, done);
});

// -------------
function errorLogger(error) {
  log(error);
}
function clean(path, done) {
  log('Cleaning: ' + $.util.colors.blue(path));
  del(path, done);
}
function log(msg) {
  if (typeof(msg) === 'object') {
    for (var item in msg) {
      if (msg.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        $.util.log($.util.colors.blue(msg[item]));
      }
    }
  } else {
    $.util.log($.util.colors.blue(msg));
  }
}
```

I've checked both my `gulpfile` (above) and my config:

```
module.exports = function () {
  var config = {
    temp: './temp/',
    alljs: [
      './src/**/*.js',
      './*.js'
    ],
    less: './src/client/styles/styles.less'
  };
  return config;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what you said.  If `clean()` is stopping the process then that is [most likely] where your problem is.

In this case, your problem is because of the `done` callback.  As of v2.0, the `del` package no longer accepts a callback... so it's never being called.  Instead, it returns a promise.  Here's the doc...

https://github.com/sindresorhus/del/releases/tag/v2.0.0